How to setup a specific ethernet interface for WSL (Ubuntu 20.04)?
On Windows 10 I have a 20.04 Ubuntu WSL and I want to connect the ethernet connection through a specific ethernet interface. On windows powershell I get this info for that specific device:
Wireless LAN adapter WLAN:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 3C-E9-F7-A7-1C-0F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5c2a:e902:799d:9451%10(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.177.238(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Mittwoch, 21. August 2024 17:10:37
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Mittwoch, 21. August 2024 18:10:37
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.177.48
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.177.48
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 104655351
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2B-50-68-10-3C-E9-F7-A7-1C-0F
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.177.48
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

and in the WSL I get for ip addr show the following:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:67:b4:8c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe67:b48c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Ok, so for now I cannot ping anything (as I tried to set that myself, but failed). So how to make sure that I can access the interner from WSL through that "WLAN" device on windows? How to set this up?

With recent releases of WSL2, this is possible using "mirrored" networking mode, but only with Windows 11 23H2. The feature has not been backported to WSL10 at this point.
(Much of the below copied from my Super User answer on a related topic), which is worth reading for any additional information.
In Mirrored Mode, the network interfaces from Windows are mirrored into WSL2, so you would be able to see and interact with the WLAN interface directly (see caveat below).
If you can upgrade to Windows 11, then the Mirrored networking mode can be enabled in WSL 2 2.0.0 (that's WSL2, using the WSL application version 2.0.0) or later installed from the Microsoft Store (or manually).
To enable Mirrored mode:

Add the following to your <windows_user_profile>/.wslconfig:
[wsl2]
networkingMode=mirrored


Exit your WSL distribution

Run wsl --shutdown from PowerShell then restart WSL


Running ip addr and ip link should now show you all of the physical interfaces (and some virtual ones as well) from Windows, with the ability to route between them as desired.
Note that WiFi interfaces in Windows will appear at wired NICs in this mode.  Some other limitations may apply, but you are at least able to bring these interfaces up and down from within WSL2.

@user68186 Ah, thanks!  As you might guess, I forgot to edit that part out when copying/pasting from my Super User answer.  I got most of the WSL1 commentary out, but missed that last part.
